# Tracking completion of a specific XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Would it be possible to determine when a particular XMLHttpRequest has completed using pure JavaScript?. Say I know the URL of a resource that will be requested with an XMLHttpRequest, for example: `http://www.mywebsite.com/test.json`, could I track the completion of this request using JavaScript?

This is the code I have so far:

```
var oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

function newXHR() {
    var realXHR = new oldXHR();
    realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(realXHR.readyState==4 && realXHR.status==200){
            console.log('request was made');
        }
    }, false);
    return realXHR;
 }
 window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
```

however, this tracks every single HTTP request made on a website and isn't very useful. I want to pinpoint the exact request and determine when it has completed. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "hijack" (override, practically) the `open()` method instead of the constructor.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (function(realOpen) {
    return function(method, url) {
        if (url === 'http://www.mywebsite.com/test.json') {
            this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
                // ...do what you have to do
            });
        }
        realOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```